# "(NO BRANCH, REBASING BRANCH_NAME)" prefixing each commit message after git rebase

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-commit

I'm trying to edit a few previous commit messages. I started by doing a

git rebase -i %%commit-hash%%

Then, I set to 'reword' all the commits I wanted to edit, and subsequently edited the commit messages in the interactive process produced by git.

However, to my surprise, now  each commit message is prefixed by: "(NO BRANCH, REBASING BRANCH_NAME)".

Why is this happening? And more importantly, how do I prevent git from inserting the prefix into my commit messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was my bad: I had previously setup some hooks so that my commit messages be automatically prefixed with a bug Id.

It seems that the hooks are triggered when doing a rebase as well, and thus messing up the produced message.

Beware brothers :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I knew it's my bad. I had a pre-commit message hook and I knew it was causing this. So I removed the hook and repeated the rebase. It didn't work. I thought that editing commit messages during *interactive* rebase is enough, but no, one has to use the `reword` command, instead of `pick`.